# Python: What is zip doing in this list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to understand this:

```
a = "hello"
b = "world"
[chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)]
```

I understand the `XOR` part but I don't get what zip is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip` combines each letter of `a` and `b` together.

```
a = "hello"
b = "world"
print zip(a, b)
>>>
    [('h', 'w'), ('e', 'o'), ('l', 'r'), ('l', 'l'), ('o', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't doing anything out of the ordinary for [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

The list slicing of `a` is overkill since `zip` assumes this behavior.

As stated in the docs:

> > > This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.