# For what do you need zip?

Tags: python

Lastly, I saw this code. I don't understand for what do you need the zip (line 4).

Here is the code which compares the nesting structure

```
def same_structure_as(original,other):
    if type(original) != type(other) or len(original) != len(other):
        return False
    for org_val, other_val in zip(original, other):
            if type(org_val) != type(other_val):
                return False
            if type(org_val) is list and type(other_val) is list:
                if not same_structure_as(org_val, other_val):
                    return False
    return True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: What is zip doing in this list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245470/python-what-is-zip-doing-in-this-list-comprehension)

Comment: Did you read the docs for zip?

Answer (score 1):

Zip allows you to iterate through two lists simultaneously. It's just a handy shortcut. So, instead of writing this code:

```
for i in range(min(len(original), len(other))): # stop at the end of the smallest list
    org_val = original[i]
    other_val = other[i]
    ...
```

You can just write:

```
for org_val, other_val in zip(original, other):
    ...
```

Although it works for iterables too, so it's not quite equivalent to the index-based code I provided, but I think it should be pretty clear anyway.